# Properties of complex-valued matrix $\mathbf{A}$ if $\mathbf{A}^H \mathbf{A}$ is close to diagonal

Tags: matrices

Let $\mathbf{A}$ be a complex-valued matrix of dimensions $M \times L$.

If the product $\mathbf{A}^H \mathbf{A}$ is close to a diagonal matrix (that is, the terms outside the main diagonal of $\mathbf{A}^H \mathbf{A}$ are close to zero), can we say something about the properties/characteristics of $\mathbf{A}$?

Comment: you can expand traces and determinants in terms of the small off diagonal entries

Comment: If it is close to a diagonal matrix it means that $A^H$ is almost the inverse to $A$, almost orthogonal. If it was almost equal to the identity it would be almost orthonormal.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. @tired, apologies for my limited understanding. What would be the aim of the expansion of the traces and determinants?